# How do I correctly link in static libraries with g++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, g++

I have a rather complex build I'm trying to do, but I'll simplify it a little bit for this question.  I have three c++ files  (main.cpp file2.cpp and file3.cpp) that I am trying to compile and link against 3 static libs (libx.a liby.z libz.a) to produce an executable.

There are many dependencies involved.

All three c files are dependent on all 3 libs. libx is dependent on liby and libz.  And finally, libx is also dependent on several callback functions contained in file2.cpp.

What command line would build this correctly? I have tried dozens of variations and nothing has satisfied the linker yet.

If it matters, the libs are pure c code compiled with gcc.  Sources are c++ and I'm compiling/linking with g++.  I have this working correctly as a visual studio project, and am trying to port to linux.

Answer (score 2):

From your post:

```
g++ main.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp -lx -ly -lz
```

However, if static linking is causing you problems, or you need to distribute any of the libs, then you may consider making them *shared objects* (`.so` files, commonly called *DSOs*).  In that case, when you build `libx.a`, for example, compile all the sources to object files, and then combine them with

```
g++ -shared *.o -o libx.so -ly -lz
```

(this version assumes that `liby.a` and `libz.a` are stills static, and will be combined into `libx.so`

Comment: and not to pollute the answer, but when you say "callback", are you passing a pointer of a function in `file1.cpp`, or have you directly referenced a function from `file1.cpp` in `libx.a`?  The former presents no issues at all, the second is bad, and indicates (without knowing more) that `file1.cpp` should be part of `libx.a`

Comment: Radical, unfortunately it is the latter, and this solution isn't working for me.

Comment: I think this command line should still fit the bill.  However, your situation isn't optimal (okay, really, it's bad software factorization).  A possible solution is to split `file1.cpp` into those parts that need to be in `libx.a`, and leave the remainder separate.  That's irrelevant to the answer, but may help your current situation.

Comment: I'm not in a position to refactor this code right now - it was created by my boss and passed on to me for porting and new feature addition.   I do agree with you though.   Not sure why this solution isn't working for me...I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: the idea is that we distribute libx to customers who then provide their own platform dependent implementation of certain functions used by libx (for example, malloc/free)

Comment: Ahh, that's an important point.  It'd be better to make your libs into _shared objects_ (`.so`s in Linux, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `extern "C" { }` in your .cpp files to include the header for the C libs.

See [Including C Headers in C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-nonsystem.html) in [How To Mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).